# jquery advice on tabbed system

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-tabs

I create a 'my account' section for a site, the site has some e-commerce functionality too it, what I wanting to create is a tab that shows the users current basket/short list and the other tab to show there purchase history.  On buying the products from the short list (this is done in a one click system using AJAX, if a success notification returns I want to be able to chage the users current tab to purchased...is this possible using jquery tabs, and if so what kind of structure would I need, I have the ajax working but cannot figure this bit out for the life of me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your just trying to select a tab after the ajax call you can call this method in your ajax callback function.

.tabs( "select" , index )

Here is a reference http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select

Answer (score 1):

I think [UI/API/1.8/Tabs - jQuery JavaScript Library](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) should help